# Auto increment sequence in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I want to auto increment `_id` in mongodb using java. I am completely new to this. In the document I found the solution like this:

```
db.counters.insert(
 {
      _id: "userid",
      seq: 0
   }
)


function getNextSequence(name) {
var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
{
query: { _id: name },
update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
new: true
}
);
return ret.seq;
}

db.users.insert(
{
_id: getNextSequence("userid"),
name: "Sarah C."
}
)
```

Can any one suggest how do I do this using java ? I am completely new to this.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540700/how-can-i-auto-increment-a-field-in-mongodb-using-java-code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) first you should create collection using mongoDB shell and collection should be as :

```
db.counters.insert(
{
  _id: "userid",
  seq: 0
})
```

So you get `counters` collections which contains field like `_id,seq`, now create `getNextSequence` function in java and this function having parameter `userid` as string so `getNextSequence` function like this :

```
public static Object getNextSequence(String name) throws Exception{
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    // Now connect to your databases
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("demo");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("counters");
    BasicDBObject find = new BasicDBObject();
    find.put("_id", name);
    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
    update.put("$inc", new BasicDBObject("seq", 1));
    DBObject obj =  collection.findAndModify(find, update);
    return obj.get("seq");
```

}

The above function return `seq` count and used this function in `main` method as like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    // Now connect to your databases
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("demo");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("counters");
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();

    document.put("_id", getNextSequence("userid"));
    document.put("name","Sarah C.");
    collection.insert(document); // insert first doc

    document.put("_id", getNextSequence("userid"));
    document.put("name", "Bob D.");
    collection.insert(document); // insert second doc
}
```

Now in `counters` collection contains three documents which contains `name` as `Sarah C. and Bob D.` respectively and one default documents which we inserted manually  at first time and it increment `seq` like this `{ "_id" : "userid", "seq" : 2 }`

Comment: What if one of the put operation fail and the sequence is not used?

Comment: What about using mlab at this moment?

Comment: is it still works or got updated since 5 years old?

Answer (score 3):

```
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("Table Name");

DBObject modifier = new BasicDBObject("counter", 1);
DBObject incQuery = new BasicDBObject("$id", modifier);
```