# How to call stored functions in MongoRepository (Spring Data) when inserting documents?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to implement [the autoincrement feature](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm) in my MongoRepository, what I've tried was hooking into the `onBeforeSave` Mongo Repository event through `AbstractMongoEventListener` and appending an `$eval` document, but I'm getting an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name $eval`

```
public void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent<Entity> event) {
    String evalQuery = "getNextSeqVal(%1$s)";
    Document evalDoc = new Document("$eval", String.format(evalQuery,
            event.getSource().getIdType()));
    event.getDocument().append("customId", evalDoc);
    super.onBeforeSave(event);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065045/auto-increment-sequence-in-mongodb-using-java

Similar question might help

Comment: @RaunakShamnani yes, that question has the `getNextSeqVal()` as a Java method not a Stored function in Mongo, I want to have the Id generation as a stored Mongo function