# Unique int _id for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to assign unique int for _id. I know that ObjectID is a great option, but I need to use int as an ID in my case. I am using Random to generate random int to assign it the new object.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error 
collection: TOP100SongsUK.artists index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 484624875 }
```

Though, it is not true. For now, my collection has a few records and that's impossible. What may be a trigger this issue?

Here is the method that writes into the DB and last method assigns an ID.

```
 public boolean add(Artist artist) {
    Document artistToInsert = new Document();
    artistToInsert.append(ARTIST_ID, assignArtistID()).append(ARTIST_NAME, artist.getName());
    boolean validOperation = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    do {
        try {
            addArtist(artistToInsert);
            validOperation = true;
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
            attempts++;
            System.out.println("Incorrect ID for Artist");
        }
    } while (!validOperation || attempts < 3);
    if (attempts == 3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to add Artist - Mongo");
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean addArtist(Document artistToInsert) {
    artistCollection.insertOne(artistToInsert);
    return true;
}

private static Random intGenerator = new Random();
 private int assignArtistID() {
        return Math.abs(intGenerator.nextInt());
}
```

UPDATED: getNextSequence Function:

```
static final String ID_PARAM = "idParam";
static final String ID_SEQ = "seq";

static int getNextSequence(MongoCollection<Document> collection){
    Document findRequest = new Document();
    findRequest.append("_id", ID_PARAM);
    Document updateRequest =  new Document();
    updateRequest.append("$inc", new Document(ID_SEQ,1));
    FindOneAndUpdateOptions options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions();
    options.upsert(true);
    options.returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER);
    Document returnDoc =  collection.findOneAndUpdate(findRequest,updateRequest,options);
    return (int) returnDoc.get(ID_SEQ);
}
```

Comment: See this article on [Generating Globally Unique Identifiers for Use with MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb). Specifically, the sub-topic "Ensure identifier uniqueness at the database level".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the code itself, not an auto-increment sequence. The loop was going on the second iteration, so the method to insert Object was called twice, but ID was the same in both cases.

The first call wrote to db with correctly incremented _id, but the loop didn't break. Thus the same object with the same id was writing to db and this caused WriteMongoException.

I removed a loop, works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use a random int to generate your _id mongo.
You should use an auto increment sequence using Mongo.

You have to create a collection for your sequence, with a sequenceName and your sequenceNumber.
Then for each insert, get your sequence, and increment it.

Here are some links to help you with that :

- [Auto increment sequence in mongodb using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065045/auto-increment-sequence-in-mongodb-using-java)
- https://mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-auto-sequence-id-example/
- https://dzone.com/articles/mongodb-java-api-using-a-sequence-collection-with

Comment: Thank you! I implemented solution, though I still get MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection. But this _id does not exist in DB 100%. Can it be an issue of the collection settings? i.e. autoIndexId: true - and I know that now it is impossible to change it to false starting with 4.0 version (I updated post at the end if you need to reference getNextSequence() )

Comment: You sure that you duplicate key error come from your _id? Did you set an other index in your collections?
Can you check with db.collection.getIndexes()?

Comment: No other Indexes were created.
Here is the full error message: E11000 duplicate key error collection: TOP100SongsUK.artists index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 3 }

Here is the output of getIndexes().
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id _",
                "ns" : "TOP100SongsUK.artists"
        }
]

Comment: ok thanks.
And when you get you duplicate key error on { _id: 3 } you don't have any document with _id: 3 already in your collection?

Comment: Yes, there is no {_id: 3} in the collection. What is more interesting It still inserts the record to the collection and then I get an exception. If I swallow the exception, it works as it is supposed to, properly adding new records without any duplicates